# Order in linked lists sometimes works and sometimes doesn't. Very weird

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, struct, linked-list

This code just attempts to create linked lists of chars. The weird thing is that sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. I really don't know why.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


struct mychar {
    char value;
    struct mychar *nextPtr;
};

typedef struct mychar Mychar;


void insert(Mychar **, char );
void printlist(Mychar *);

int main(){
    Mychar *startPtr = NULL;

    while (1) {
        char letter;
        printf("\nScrivi il carattere da aggiungere: ");
        scanf("\n%c", &letter);

        insert(&startPtr, letter);

        printlist(startPtr);
    }
}


void insert(Mychar **sPtr, char newvalue){
    Mychar *newnodePtr = calloc(1, sizeof(Mychar));
    if (!newnodePtr){
        printf("\n\nError in memory allocation.\n\n");
        return;
    }
    newnodePtr->value = newvalue;

    Mychar *previousPtr = NULL;
    Mychar *currentPtr = *sPtr;

    while ( currentPtr!=NULL && newvalue > (currentPtr->value) ){
        previousPtr = currentPtr;
        currentPtr = currentPtr->nextPtr;
    }

    if (previousPtr==NULL){
        newnodePtr->nextPtr = NULL;
        *sPtr = newnodePtr;
    } else {
        previousPtr->nextPtr = newnodePtr;
        newnodePtr->nextPtr = currentPtr;
    }
}

void printlist(Mychar *sPtr){
    Mychar *currentPtr = sPtr;
    while (currentPtr!=NULL){
        printf("%c", currentPtr->value);
        currentPtr = currentPtr->nextPtr;
    }
}
```

Output1 (doesn't seem to work, **when a minor letter is added all the nodes disappear**):

```
Write the char to add: a
a
Write the char to add: b
ab
Write the char to add: c
abc
Write the char to add: z
abcz
Write the char to add: a
a
Write the char to add: b
ab
Write the char to add: z
abz
Write the char to add: a
a
Write the char to add: ^C
```

Output 2 (seems to work):

```
Write the char to add: A
A
Write the char to add: B
AB
Write the char to add: C
ABC
Write the char to add: a
ABCa
Write the char to add: z
ABCaz
Write the char to add: a
ABCaaz
Write the char to add: b
ABCaabz
Write the char to add: Z
ABCZaabz
Write the char to add: ^C
```

Also, I'd like to free all the nodes created when I exit the program (with Ctrl+c for example)..

How could I free all of the dynamically allocated nodes?

Comment: Not related to your question, but you shouldn't assign `newnodePtr->value = newvalue;` before you have verified that `newnodePtr` is not null.

Comment: Your new node's `nextPtr` value isn't properly set when doing mid or head position insertions.And fyi, that insertion could me made considerably simpler while fixing your problem. Easy repro case, btw. just repeatedly add `'a'`

Comment: @MOehm well, you are right. edited it!

Comment: @WhozCraig how?

Comment: Well, your problem occurs when you insert a character at the front: `newnodePtr->nextPtr = NULL`. By setting the "next" link to null, you cut the list short, but you want to append the rest of the list: `... = *sptr`.

Comment: @MOehm you are right. This fixed my problem. Also, how could I free all of the dynamically allocated nodes?

Comment: Traverse the list and `free(p)` the memory. But take care not to pull away the rug from under your feet: You should store the next link in a temporaty variable in order to to access `p->next` after `p` was deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't properly wire the new node's `nextPtr` member in the case when the node will be the new list head. You can fix that, as well as significantly simplify the insertion, by doing this:

```
void insert(Mychar **sPtr, char newvalue)
{
    while (*sPtr && (*sPtr)->value < newvalue)
        sPtr = &(*sPtr)->nextPtr;

    Mychar *newPtr = malloc(sizeof *newPtr);
    if (!newPtr)
    {
        perror("Failed to allocate new node");
        return;
    }
    newPtr->value = newvalue;
    newPtr->nextPtr = *sPtr;
    *sPtr = newPtr;
}
```

This technique has the added benefit of handling all cases of insertion implicitly, including head, mid, and tail positions.

And since you asked how to free the list, the above code should give you some insights, but it could look something like this:

```
void freelist(Mychar **sPtr)
{
    while (*sPtr)
    {
        Mychar *tmp = *sPtr;
        *sPtr = tmp->nextPtr;
        free(tmp);
    }
}
```